# ImportError - deploy Falcon app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, falconframework

I'm having an ImportError after deploying to Elastic Beanstalk. We're running Falcon to make an API. I have successfully used the EB CLI to initialise an app, create the environment and deploy my code. We use Python 2.7 (for now).

The AWS EB site for the app/environment says everything went well, but when I send a request to the api, the logs show this error:

```
[Wed Nov 30 06:02:25.555507 2016] [:error] [pid 29352] [remote 127.0.0.1:56624] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 30 06:02:25.555524 2016] [:error] [pid 29352] [remote 127.0.0.1:56624]   File "/opt/python/current/app/api/app.py", line 12, in <module>
[Wed Nov 30 06:02:25.555549 2016] [:error] [pid 29352] [remote 127.0.0.1:56624]     from middlewares import require_json
[Wed Nov 30 06:02:25.555566 2016] [:error] [pid 29352] [remote 127.0.0.1:56624] ImportError: No module named middlewares
[Wed Nov 30 06:02:26.558411 2016] [:error] [pid 29352] [remote 127.0.0.1:60720] mod_wsgi (pid=29352): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/api/app.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

Locally my imports work just fine. The relevant parts of the api look like this:

```
-api/
    -__init__.py #import app
    -app.py
    -middlewares/
        -__init__.py #import require_json
        -require_json.py
```

Line 12 of my app.py file:

```
from middlewares import require_json
```

But the logs are consistently saying this is an ImportError. Any thoughts on what's happened here? I'm baffled.

As for the `__init__.py` files importing modules; this is a legacy code base and I'm not sure what the implications are for changing that just yet, other than the tests will fail.

**EDIT**

This morning I've tried commenting out those import lines, but that just gives me errors on the next import:

```
[Wed Nov 30 21:52:00.699228 2016] [:error] [pid 11254] [remote 172.31.8.163:37352] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 30 21:52:00.699245 2016] [:error] [pid 11254] [remote 172.31.8.163:37352]   File "/opt/python/current/app/api/app.py", line 15, in <module>
[Wed Nov 30 21:52:00.699270 2016] [:error] [pid 11254] [remote 172.31.8.163:37352]     import resources
[Wed Nov 30 21:52:00.699288 2016] [:error] [pid 11254] [remote 172.31.8.163:37352] ImportError: No module named resources
```

I've also done what's recommended in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810589/cannot-locate-modules-of-django-app-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk).

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/python/current/app')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way your code appears to be structured, you shouldn't be pointing `WSGIScriptAlias` directive of Apache at your `app.py` file directly.

What you need to do is create a separate WSGI script file to use with `WSGIScriptAlias` and in it have:

```
from api.app import application
```

You will also need to configure mod_wsgi so that the parent directory of the `api` directory is in the Python module search path. You can do in the mod_wsgi configuration, or do it in this new WSGI script file.

Presuming you had added the WSGI script file as `app.wsgi` in the same directory as `api` appears as a subdirectory, it could include:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

from api.app import application
```

Comment: Thank you... I mistakenly thought I didn't need a WSGI script, this works now.

Comment: The problem is that you were reaching into a code file, by path, which was a part of a Python package. Due to that, Python had no sense of where the root for the package was.